# Adding location to Querying the Graph API with Python

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

My query currently looks like the one below... I am trying to narrow my search to a specific location (West Midlands). How can I achieve that.

```
pp(g.request("search", {'q' : 'student mentors', 'type': 'page', 'location': 'West Midlands'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no location parameter for query type page. You can add "West Midlands" to the query parameter itself because Facebook searches the location/address, too. So you call would be

```
pp(g.request("search", {'q' : 'student mentors west midlands', 'type': 'page'}))
```

However that specific query does not return any results, which means there is no page that includes "student mentors" in it's name and "west midlands" in it's address.

Comment: Many thanks! That does make sense. I have used United Kingdom instead and generated results. Thanks again